# Why is adding two matrices badly slow after transpose?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I want to add a transposed one to a numpy matrix but

```
matot = mato.transpose() #4.3e-6s
mato = mato + matot #557087.4e-6s
```

a random matrix is much faster

```
matot = numpy.random.randn(dim, dim) #144453.7e-6s
mato = mato + matot #15740.5e-6s
```

And I found `numpy.reshape` is also slow after transpose.
Are there some tricks about this problem?

Comment: Can you please show how `mato` is defined?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it can be a random one, the result is the same.

Comment: What is the shape of the 2d array? is it broadcasting when adding?

Comment: `transpose` is fast because it majes a `view` - new array, but sharred dara buffer.   Reshape of transpoae) makes a copy. There are no tricks.

Comment: @FBruzzesi it’s a square matrix like 10*10. it will not broadcast I think

Comment: @hpaulj it is the worst :(

Comment: `mato + mato.T.copy()` improves the speed a bit.  The transpose changes strides from (80,8) to (8,80), and apparently adding the two arrays results in some complicated iteration in compiled code.  The `copy` makes a new array, with the original order.  This takes time, but the overall addition time is reduced.  But that's an undocumented implementation detail.

Comment: Transposing 10x10 matrix should not take more than few microseconds (on any decent hardware). Clearly not 550 us. There is probably something wrong in the environment (python numpy bug, parallel overhead, memory swapping / out-of-memory, insanely slow processor, energy governor, etc.). Your code runs in 0.9 us on my machine. The one of @hpaulj runs in 0.8 us (std: 0.1 us). Out of curiosity, what is your processor, your Numpy version and your OS?